# No matching function for the call of foo

Tags: c++, templates

Why I am getting Build error for the below code

compiler used c++14 xcode 8.3.3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<typename T, typename U>

void foo(std::array<T,sizeof(U)> x,
         std::array<U,sizeof(T)> y,
         int z)
{

    puts(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

int main()
{

    foo(std::array<int,8>{},std::array<double,4>{},1);
    foo(std::array<int,9>{},std::array<double,4>{},2);

}
```

**Error**
Getting error for second call

```
foo(std::array<int,9>{},std::array<double,4>{},2);
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6a265786fe3e909f)

```
g++ -std=c++1z -fconcepts -fgnu-tm  -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread -pedantic-errors main.cpp -lm  -latomic -lstdc++fs && ./a.out
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:18:14: error: could not convert 'std::array<int, 9>{}' from 'std::array<int, 9>' to 'std::array<int, 8>'
     foo(std::array<int,9>{},std::array<double,4>{},2);
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'void foo(std::array<T, sizeof (U)>, std::array<U, sizeof (T)>, int) [with T = int; U = double]':
main.cpp:17:53:   required from here
main.cpp:6:34: warning: unused parameter 'x' [-Wunused-parameter]
 void foo(std::array<T,sizeof(U)> x,
                                  ^
main.cpp:7:34: warning: unused parameter 'y' [-Wunused-parameter]
          std::array<U,sizeof(T)> y,
                                  ^
main.cpp:8:14: warning: unused parameter 'z' [-Wunused-parameter]
          int z)
          ^
```

But if there is a single call it works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>


template<typename T, typename U>

void foo(std::array<T,sizeof(U)> x,
         std::array<U,sizeof(T)> y,
         int z)
{

    puts(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}


int main()
{

    foo(std::array<int,8>{},std::array<double,4>{},1);
    //foo(std::array<int,9>{},std::array<double,4>{},2);

}
```

Output

```
void foo(std::array<T, sizeof(U)>, std::array<U, sizeof(T)>, int) [T = int, U = double]
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: Is the problem the second call, or both calls?  What exactly is the error message, and which version of which compiler on which platform generates the error?  What compilation options are you using?

Comment: The screenshot isn't a benefit to the question, beyond showing that you're using XCode on a Mac.  Avoid screenshots on SO; they more often a diversion than a help.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sorry for that I don't know why I am not getting the same kind of verbose of error  in xcode ..I have added a demo link

Comment: I work on a Mac, but I learned to program before there were IDEs for Unix, so I still don't tend to use them in general, or XCode in particular.  You show the command line error messages — that makes sense.  I'm not sure you should still be using `-std=c++1z`;  I can use `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14` or `-std=c++17` and get the same message.  However, that too is tangential to the issue, which is the mismatched dimensions on the arrays in the second call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is at the line:

```
foo(std::array<int,9>{},std::array<double,4>{},2);
```

In order to understand the error, let's try to do the "compiler-job" and try to understand how the template function `foo` is called.

So.

The function `foo` has 2 types to deduces: `T` and `U`.

When you call `foo` with that statement, you're passing two arguments:

- `std::array<int, 9>`
- `std::array<double, 4>`

And your template function accepts:

- `std::array<T,sizeof(U)> x`
- `std::array<U,sizeof(T)> y`

So it's easy to see that `T` is mapped as `int` and `U` as `double`.

The deduced function will became:

```
void foo(std::array<int, 8>,
         std::array<double, 4>,
         int);
```

Because likely on your architecture `sizeof(double) = 8` and `sizeof(int) = 4` (I've just substituted the `sizeof`s).

So your calling is wrong because your first parameter is `std::array<int, 9>` instead of `std::array<int, 8>`.

Indeed, your previous calling:

```
foo(std::array<int,8>{},std::array<double,4>{},1);
```

compiles.

Answer (score 2):

With GCC 7.2.0 on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.6, I get the errors (from the source in the question saved in `tf71.cpp`):

```
$ g++ -O3 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror tf71.cpp -o tf71
tf71.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
tf71.cpp:18:14: error: could not convert ‘std::array<int, 9>{}’ from ‘std::array<int, 9>’ to ‘std::array<int, 8>’
     foo(std::array<int,9>{},std::array<double,4>{},2);
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
tf71.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void foo(std::array<T, sizeof (U)>, std::array<U, sizeof (T)>, int) [with T = int; U = double]’:
tf71.cpp:17:53:   required from here
tf71.cpp:6:34: error: unused parameter ‘x’ [-Werror=unused-parameter]
 void foo(std::array<T,sizeof(U)> x,
                                  ^
tf71.cpp:7:34: error: unused parameter ‘y’ [-Werror=unused-parameter]
          std::array<U,sizeof(T)> y,
                                  ^
tf71.cpp:8:14: error: unused parameter ‘z’ [-Werror=unused-parameter]
          int z)
              ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

The problem with the second call is that the `9` isn't the size of the the `double` type in the second `std::array<double, 4>`, so the template isn't matched.  It's an improbable looking template function.

The unused parameter errors are inevitable given the body of the function and the compilation options used; they're tangential to the problem at hand.

Comment: I am getting the error as you have mentioned , I have added the snapshot